# Check if file contains string in VB6

Tags: string, file, vb6

How do I check if a certain textfile contains a certain string?
Would I have to actually open the file and use InStr(), or is there a more convenient way to do it?

By the way, the language is Visual Basic 6.0

Comment: Yes, you will need to load the file first. If it's too large to fit in memory, load it in pieces.

Comment: Check this out if you're after drop-in code http://www.veign.com/code-view.php?type=app&codeid=72.

Comment: Easiest component to manage (text) files is FileSystemObject (referenced in Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You can't without opening a file, but there's an alternative (also involves file opening) you can use the Shell, as follows:

```
<filename> is the name of the file
<string> is the string you want to check
```

(Assuming the file you want to check is in the current directory)

```
    Shell("find /c "+chr(34)+"<string>"+chr(34)+" <filename>  > test.txt")

    Open "test.txt" for input as #1
        input #1, A
    Close #1

    If (Right(A,3)=": 0") Then 
            Msgbox "Does not exist"
    Else
            Msgbox "String exists"
    End if
```

Although this also involves opening the file, it will be a lot faster (if the file is huge) than searching the string using InStr( ) function, because it checks for a constant string now. Also, you can change the shell command a bit to search for the text in multiple files (using wildcard) at the same time, which will definitely be a lot lot faster than using a loop to open all those files and using another loop to read all the lines and using InStr() on each line.

Comment: He asks how to do it using VB6 and you suggest using `find`, really? How would you check for errors (say, command shell failed to create your `test.txt`)? I also doubt that claims about significantly superior performance of your solution are well founded. And I'm curious if `Right(A, 3)=": 0"` is still a correct check in, say, right-to-left locale.

Comment: if command-shell failed to create the file 'test.txt', we can always check using the PathFileExists() Win32 API; and I believe that opening a file in VB, followed by a loop for reading each line in the file and then using InStr() on each line, would be slower compared to using "Find". As far as the locale you are referring to, yes, I admit that it might be a problem though.